# Emails are not sent

Tags: 8, emails

I am running Drupal 8 on a DigitalOcean server. I am trying to use the standard Drupal 8 Contact form to get user's email addresses. I currently have the form up and it is visible and holds the information I want but when the user submits their message the form does not send an email to the address that it is set to and two pop ups tell the user that the email is not sent and the message is sent. The message is saved to the contact form storage module that I have downloaded but the email is not sent out. Can anyone help me solve this? I have checked my MX records and the email address that is used in the contact form and is a valid gmail that I have control of and is currently redirected from our server. I am unsure how to solve this issue please help

Comment: I have added SMTP and set it up according to guides I've found online and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you don't have an MTA(Mail Transfer Agent) installed/configured on your droplet. You need to install **Postfix** so that it can be used to send emails by local applications.

Below is some info from DigitalOcean tutorials library on how to install/setup/test Postfix.

[How To Install and Setup Postfix on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[How To Install and Configure Postfix as a Send-Only SMTP Server on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[How To Install and Configure Postfix on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04)

[How to Install and Configure Postfix as a Send-Only SMTP Server on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)

---

Another option is to use [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module

> This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send email directly to an SMTP server. The module supports SMTP authentication and can even connect to servers using SSL if supported by PHP.

Comment: I have added SMTP Authentication Support found at [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp). Do I still need to set up postfix in order to get this to work? I have followed guides on the SMTP Authentication support such as [link](http://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/configure-drupal-smtp-gmail) and it is all set up according to that blog on my end but still does not work.

Comment: @P.Burden You don't need to install Postfix for SMTP Auth module to work. The module is in early stages of development and there are pending patches that you should keep an eye on. Are there any errors in dblog (admin/reports/dblog). Did you try enabling debug mode in SMTP module settings, to check if everything is in order?

Comment: edit: **SMTP module's version for D8** is in early stages of development.

Comment: There are errors in dblog. I did enable debug mode in SMTP module settings, I was unsure where to find these logs thank you. The most recent one says Type: mail Date: Thursday, Jun 9, 2016 -18:54 User P.Burden Location: mysite.com/admin/config/systems/smtp Referrer: mysite.com/admin/config/systems/smtp Message: Error sending email (from P.Burden@mysite.com to P.Burden@gmail.com with reply-to not set). Severity: Error Hostname my host Operations

Comment: Is there at least a way to keep the message that says the email is not sent from being displayed or would you sugges that I set up postfix?

Comment: @P.Burden  The message from log is not very descriptive. Go back to the page where you defined settings for SMPT Auth module and send test email from there. The debug message should be printed on the same page. If you can't figure out what is the issue from there, then give a shot to Postfix. Email deliverability is always a sensitive subject. Setting up Postfix will open the door to the multitude of other settings that need to be done right in order for your emails to actually end up in users' inboxes instead of spam folders (DKIM, SPF, etc.)

Comment: It says SMTP module is active.
A test e-mail has been sent to pburden11@gmail.com via SMTP. You may want to check the log for any error messages.
The configuration options have been saved.
Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.
I will start reading up on Postfix as well thanks for your help so far

Comment: @P.Burden Another thought - while using SMTP module with Gmail account, make sure you allow "Access to less secure apps" in your gmail account settings. Follow [this link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) while logged into gmail to enable that setting. Most likely this little setting was the culprit of failed emails.